# Ajax call to .html file stripped out the HTML comments

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, html

As the title states, I made an Ajax call to a .html file which included html tags and html comments.

However sometimes (and it's not reproducible every time) the response is returned with all the HTML comments stripped out.  Only the HTML tags remain.

The comment tags are essential to the .html file b/c it's part of how we do template rendering.

We run a typical LAMP stack (Apache), if that helps.  Does Apache sometimes strip tags randomly from .html files?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that apache strips comments from your HTML files:
http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/config.html

Have you verified that your ajax responseText does not contain any comments?

Comment: it's intermittent, so does Apache sometimes strip and sometimes not strip?  Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes I have verified that responseText does not contain comments with firebug.

Comment: @resopollution if it's intermittent, is it possible that you've got more than one Apache server in a rendering cluster or something, and that some Apache instances are configured differently than others?

Comment: all running on 1 server, multiple processes, but with same configuration =/

Comment: at this point I don't even know if it's server side or client side